# Rails 4 precompiling unwanted files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, assets, production-environment

Rails precompiles unwanted font files, since that `.eot`, `.woff`, `.svg` and `.ttf` formats aren't in `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` list.

**/app/assets/stylesheets/subscriber/font-awesome.css.scss**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.1.0');
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.1.0') format('woff'),
  url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.1.0') format('truetype'),
  url('fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.1.0') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And my fonts are placed in `app/assets/fonts/subscriber` folder.

**precompile formats:**

```
$ rails c -e production
Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.2)
2.0.0-p353 :001 > y Rails.application.config.assets.precompile
---
- !ruby/object:Proc {}
- !ruby/regexp /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/
- active_admin.js
- active_admin.css
- active_admin/print.css
 => nil
```

I have no idea why Rails precompiling them. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary from the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline):

If you don't want your assets precompiled, put them in the `public/assets` folder and not in the `app/assets` folder.